# PIC18 read from oled (for scrolling)

Tags: c, pic, mplab, pic18

I am trying to scroll in line by replacing an existing line with the new one.
For this purpose i need to read data from Oled screen(from RAM). I am using MPLAB IDE, which includes this macro:

```
#define ReadData(readByte) TRISD = 0xFF;oledD_C = 1;Nop();oledRD = 0;Nop();oledRD = 1;Nop();oledRD = 0;Nop();readByte = PORTD;
```

I have converted this macro to be a funtion:

```
BYTE ReadData() 
{
    TRISD = 0xFF;   //all 8 bits are all inputs (1)
    oledD_C = 1;
    Nop();
    oledRD = 0;
    Nop();
    oledRD = 1;
    Nop();
    oledRD = 0;
    Nop();
    return PORTD;
 }
```

The code below shows how i am using this function:

```
void oledScrollIn(char* line)
{
    int i, j, counter=0, mask = 0;
    char oldLetter, newLetter;
    int currData = 0, newData = 0, oldData = 0;

    int byte = 0;
    char* b = line;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        //scroll - set page
        WriteCommand(0x40 + i);

        //start Read_Modify_Write
        WriteCommand(0xe0);

        //set page
        WriteCommand(0);
        //set column
        WriteCommand(0x00+0);
        WriteCommand(0x10+0);

        mask = (mask << 1) | 1;
        //end Read_Modify_Write
        WriteCommand(0xee);

        for (j = 0; j < 131 && *b; j++)
        {
            //set page to the last page in the screent
            //WriteCommand(0xB8);   

            if (*b)
            {
                newData = g_pucFont[*b - ' '][j%5];
            }
            else
            {
                newData = 0x00;
            }

            oldData = ReadData();   //Read
            currData = ( ( oldData&(~mask) ) | ( newData&mask ) );  // Modify
            WriteData(currData);    //Write

            if (j%5 == 0 )
            {
                if (counter > 0) *b++;
                else ++counter;
            }
        }

        //end Read_Modify_Write
        WriteCommand(0xee);

        //delay
        DelayMs(100);
    }
}
```

I have a problem to read from Oled so i can't swith the lines.
Could anyone help me?
Thank you!!!

Comment: What is the problem? You never say, just "I have a problem" which really doesn't contain a lot of information.

Comment: @unwind ReadData function returns 0 every time i call it. Another question: Is my solution right or should i rewrite it?

Comment: The return value of function `ReadData` is constant so it should be the address of `PORTD`,  `return` is only  asm instruction wich return byte constant in WREG.

Comment: Does it return zero even when you force one pin high, say with a pullup?